# Updating object from ListView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

i have a class `Product` that is displayed with a listview, in this listview i have a textbox that represent the `ProductOwner`. What i can't achieve is to update the Product Object from the listview. many people will say why not using DataGrid? because i want to try with a listview.

My XAML code:

```
<Window
x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow">

<Grid>


    <ListView Name="ListView">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="100"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Reference" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Reference}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Owner" Width="100">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Width="90" Name="TextBox"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button Name="Button" Content="Submit" Width="120" Height="25" Background="Azure" Click="Button_OnClick"></Button>
</Grid>
```

the button is here to update the ProductOwner from the current Product.

The code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Width = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - 100;
        Height = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - 100;
        Product product = new Product
        {
          Name  = "name1",
          Reference = "reference1",
          Owner = "owner1"
        };
        Product product2 = new Product
        {
            Name = "name2",
            Reference = "reference2",
            Owner = ""
        };


        List<Product> list = new List<Product>();
        list.Add(product);
        list.Add(product2);
        InitializeComponent();
        ListView.ItemsSource = list;
    }


    private void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //update product1 and product2

    }
}
```

In the Button OnClick event, the value in the textbox will update the value of the object.
I know this question is already on stackoverflow, but it doesn't cover my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to the matching property of your class (`Product.Owner`):

```
<TextBox Width="90" Name="TextBox" Text="{Binding Owner, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**Edit**

The property is updated when the `TextBox` looses the focus. This behavior can be changed by setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger` in the binding to `PropertyChanged` or `Explicit`.

For details, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: yes but what do i need to do in when the event is fired ?

Comment: You won't be able to bind it anywhere because there is no DataContext attached to it. Follow our advice from the WPF chatroom and learn about MVVM, that will make sense once you learn it.

Comment: @redaa: You don't need the event. The binding updates the property of your class when the TextBox looses the focus